# Error dealing with foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, data-migration

I'm currently having a Foreign Key issue with a project I'm working on.  I'm using Entity Code First to create my DB.  Here is what I have thus far.

### Tables

Units: Id, ...

Category: Id, ...

CategoryUnits: Id, CategoryId, UnitId

### Code First

Category.cs

```
public partial class Category : BaseEntity, ILocalizedEntity
{
    private ICollection<CategoryUnits> _categoryUnits;

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<CategoryUnits> CategoryUnits
    {
        get { return _categoryUnits ?? (_categoryUnits = new List<CategoryUnits>()); }
        protected set { _categoryUnits = value; }
    }
}
```

Units.cs

```
public class Units : BaseEntity
{
    ...
}
```

CategoryUnits.cs

```
public partial class CategoryUnits : BaseEntity, ILocalizedEntity
{
    public virtual int UnitId { get; set; }
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Units Unit { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

CategoryUnitsMap.cs

```
public partial class CategoryUnitsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<CategoryUnits>
{
    public CategoryUnitsMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("CategoryUnits");
        this.HasKey(cu => cu.Id);

        this.HasRequired(cu => cu.Unit)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(cu => cu.UnitId);

        this.HasRequired(cu => cu.Category)
            .WithMany(c => c.CategoryUnits)
            .HasForeignKey(cu => cu.CategoryId);
    }
}
```

Currently what's happening is I get the following message when I try to insert data during a data migration program:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "CategoryUnits_Category". The conflict occurred in database "NopDB3", table "dbo.Category", column 'Id'.

Here is the code where I'm actually putting data into the table.

Program.cs

```
private static void AddDefaultOfficeSuppliesUnitRights()
    {
        try
        {
            var unitIds = new List<int>();
            var sqlSelectStatement = "Select * From Units With(NoLock)";
            var units = new DataSet();

            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectStatement, sqlCon))
            {
                var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
                sqlCon.Open();
                sqlAdapter.Fill(units);
                sqlCon.Close();
            }

            foreach (DataRow dr in units.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                var unitId = Int32.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString());
                unitIds.Add(unitId);
            }

            var sqlInsertStatement = GenerateCategoryUnitsForOfficeSupplies("Insert Into CategoryUnits (UnitId, CategoryId) Values (cuUnitId, 19)", unitIds);
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsertStatement, sqlCon))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlCon.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Default Office Supply CategoryUnits Added");
        }
        //Something went wrong
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in Add Default Category Units for Office Supplies: " + ex.Message);
        }
        //Close out sql connection
        finally
        {
            if (sqlCon.State != ConnectionState.Closed) sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }

private static string GenerateCategoryUnitsForOfficeSupplies(string sqlInsertStatement, List<int> unitIds)
    {
        var sqlInsertStatements = string.Empty;
        foreach (var unitId in unitIds)
        {
            sqlInsertStatements += sqlInsertStatement.Replace("cuUnitId", unitId.ToString()) + "; ";
        }

        return sqlInsertStatements;
    }
```

The oddest thing about this is when I manually insert the data by sql statement, it works fine and has no errors.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: It is likely you are inserting data into the foriegn key field which doesn't have a corrisponding value in the primary key column...

Comment: You're right.  I realized it just a few minutes ago that the data I need in Categories is not yet populated.  I've moved the method that triggers the default data to load to the very end of the migration.  Thanks!

Comment: I will make the above an answer then if that is cool?...